# get rid of Jerky CATransition on iphone from switch view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I use this code to make the transition between a subview and another but the animation is jerky in my iphone but not in the simulator!

Any help appreciated.

UIView *currentView =mysubview;

```
[currentView setHidden:TRUE];//hide previous view
PoemResults *view1=[[PoemResults alloc] initWithNibName:@"PoemResults" bundle:nil];
[currentView addSubview:view1.view];
[currentView setHidden:FALSE];

// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
```

animation.delegate=self;

```
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[mysubview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1w"];
```

Comment: If your view is large or overly complicated, jerkiness is to be expected on a device.  In the simulator, it's like having an iPhone hard wired to a Mac, being that you can use the resources available on the system to speed everything up.

Comment: Actually the view is included with a subview some button are in the main view some of them are in the subview maybe this is the problem. I just wanted to know if there is a solution on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution found i have used different catransition that worked with no jerky animation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use this UIView class method instead?

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView 
            toView:(UIView *)toView 
            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
            options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
            completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

I've never done it like your doing it, but this would be my first try.

---

I recently had a problem with UIImageView when the resolution of the image was not the same as the one to which I was displaying it. I would get a fuzzy animation. You can look to that option if you haven't already did.

Comment: is your view a UIImageView? Or do you have UIImageView in there? I've encountered a problem with those recently.

Comment: I have an uiview which contains uibuttons.
This uiview contains another uiview which contains uibuttons and uiimageviews.